# error with jquery offset

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a div to appear underneath another div so that I can slide the top div down to reveal the appended second.

I'm pretty far off, but I keep getting an error that jquery's `[offset][1]` (which I'd like to use to get the position of the top div) is returning undefined.

Maybe this is just the wrong approach for this. Any help is appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.obscure').on('click', function() {

        var blueDiv = $('.blue').clone();

      //  blueDiv.css('display', 'none');
        $('#wrapper').append(blueDiv);
        var obscure = $('#obscure');
        var offset = obscure.offset();
        console.log(offset);
        /*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined */
        var y = offset.top;
        var x = offset.left;
        console.log(y);
        //blueDiv.css('top', y);


        $('.obscure').css('z-index', 10000);



    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/loren_hibbard/U7tAV/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean `var obscure = $('#obscure');` to read `var obscure = $('.obscure');`?